Countable zero-sets are $C$-embedded?
I was browsing Gillman and Jerison for known relations between zero-sets, $C$-embedded sets and so on.
The spaces I'm considering are $T_{3.5}$.
There are two properties that pseudocompact spaces have

All countable $C$-embedded sets are compact

All countable zero-sets are compact


Where (1) is equivalent to pseudocompactness, but (2) isn't.
A countable closed discrete $C^*$-embedded $G_\delta$-set in a pseudocompact space doesn't have to be either a zero-set nor $C$-embedded, as Katetov's example $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\Lambda = \beta\mathbb{R}\setminus (\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N})$ shows.
A zero-set need not be $C^*$-embedded, nor does a $C$-embedded set need to be closed.
A zero-set is $C^*$-embedded iff $C$-embedded.
However, a countable $C$-embedded set is closed.
Must a countable zero-set be $C$-embedded?

Most of the following can be found in Gillman and Jerison.

Lemma Subsets $A,B\subseteq X$ are completely separated if and only if they are contained in disjoint zero-sets. $\quad\blacksquare$

A subset $A\subseteq X$ is well-embedded if it is completely separated from any disjoint zero-set.

Corollary Every zero-set is well-embedded. $\quad\blacksquare$

A subspace $A\subseteq X$ is z-embedded if every zero-set of $A$ is the trace of a zero-set of $X$. Every C$^*$-embedded subspace is z-embedded. The following result is found in the paper On the Structure of a Class of Archimedian Lattice-Ordered Algebras by Henriksen and Johnson, where it is attributed to Jerison.

Proposition A Lindelöf subspace of a Tychonoff space is z-embedded. $\quad\blacksquare$

In fact, there is a kind of converse for this last statement: a Tychonoff space $X$ is z-embedded in every Tychonoff space containing it if and only if $X$ is either Lindelöf or almost-compact.
Finally we have the following, which I believe is due to Blair and Hager.

Proposition A subspace $A\subseteq X$ is C-embedded if and only if it is both z-embedded and well-embedded.

This gives us the following.

Corollary Any z-embedded zero set is C-embedded. $\quad\blacksquare$


Corollary If $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $A\subseteq X$ is a Lindelöf zero-set, then $A$ is C-embedded in $X$. $\quad\blacksquare$


Corollary If $X$ is a Tychonoff space, then every countable zero-set of $X$ is C-embedded. $\quad\blacksquare$


I only encountered $z$-embedded sets in "Dimension theory" by Charalambous, but they give a very cut out treatment, since its not the focus of the book. Also some things about $C^*$-embedded, but not $C$-embedded sets (but I learned those in Gillman and Jerison). Do you have any good sources for concepts such as $z$-embedded and well-embedded?

I think the paper Extensions of Zero-Sets and of Real-Valued Functions by Blair and Hager collects a few statements and has a decent bibliography. A lot of papers cite the text book Normal Topological Spaces by Alò and Shapiro as general reference for z-embeddings, but the book seems to be pretty rare and I've never seen a copy myself.

By the way, Extensions of Zero-Sets and of Real-Valued Functions by Blair and Hager refers to well-embedded sets as property $(\gamma)$ (all results present here are proven in that article). Where does the name "well-embedded" come from?

I never realised before that Blair didn't use the term, as it's fairly standard now. I guess I must have picked it by reading K. Yamazaki's papers. Apparently the terminology was introduced in Moran's 1970 paper Measures on Metacompact Spaces.

Perhaps its interesting to point out that corollary 4.2 from Extensions of Zero-Sets and of Real-Valued Functions by Blair and Hager also gives us a partial converse i.e. a Lindelöf C-embedded set is closed. This is a particular case of the fact that Lindelöf spaces are realcompact and a realcompact $C$-embedded set is closed.

Or another: a Lindelöf subspace of a Tychonoff space is a zero-set if and only if it is a C-embedded $G_\delta$-subset.

Call $S$ strongly well-embedded if $S$ is completely separated from each disjoint closed set. This property implies $S$ is closed, and a zero-set if its $G_\delta$. A space $X$ is normal iff every closed subspace is strongly well-embedded. And a Lindelöf well-embedded subspace is strongly well-embedded. One of the implications in above comment follows from these facts.

$S$ is strongly well-embedded iff well-embeded and has a neighbourhood base of cozero sets. But $S$ has a neighbourhood base of cozero sets in every space its embedded in iff $S$ is Lindelöf, so these results are pretty precise.

All countable zero-sets are $C$-embedded.
I'll need the following from the book "Rings of continuous functions" by Gillman and Jerison.
Completely separated: Sets $D_1, D_2$ are completely separated if there exists disjoint zero sets $D_1\subseteq Z_1, D_2\subseteq Z_2$.
Theorem 1.17: If $Y\subseteq X$, then $Y$ is $C^*$-embedded in $X$ iff completely separated sets in $Y$ are completely separated in $X$.
Exercise 3B.1: If $D$ is countable and $F$ is closed, $D\cap F = \emptyset$, then there exists a zero-set $Z$ with $D\cap Z = \emptyset$ and $Z\supseteq F$.
Exercise 1F.1: A $C^*$-embedded zero-set is $C$-embedded

Let $D$ be a countable zero-set and $D_1, D_2\subseteq D$ be disjoint zero-sets of $D$. Thus $D_1, D_2$ are disjoint countable closed sets in $X$. From exercise 3B.1 there exists a zero set $Z_1\supseteq D_1$ of $X$ with $Z_1\cap D_2 = \emptyset$, and we can assume $Z_1\subseteq Z$ by replacing $Z_1$ with $Z_1\cap Z$ since $Z$ is a zero-set. Similarly, since $Z_1$ is countable, we can now find a zero-set $Z_2$ with $Z_1\cap Z_2 = \emptyset$ and $Z_2\supseteq D_2$. Thus $D_1, D_2$ are completely separated in $X$. From Urysohn's lemma 1.17, $D$ is $C^*$-embedded, hence $C$-embedded.
